# Make webview in a tablet simulate a small device

Tags: android, android-webview, viewport

I have a mobile website that is very well suited for small devices, like smartphones, but it **doesn't look good on a tablet**.

I am using a **webview** to display the website. This webview occupies all of the screen area. Is there any way I can make the **webview simulate a small device**?

[image]

I didn't quite get from the docs what combination of options (`getLoadWithOverviewMode`, `setUseWideViewPort`, `setDefaultZoom`) will make me achieve what I want. Any help will be appreciated.

Obs: I already tried setting the text zoom (`setTextZoom(int)`). It got a little better, but not as good as on the smartphone.

Obs2: I **cannot** change the website. :(

**UPDATE:**

If I change the webview width to 720 px, the html page changes to the mobile layout and displays nicely. Now I want to do this but keeping the webview with full width. Like tricking the html page to think that the webview width is smaller than it really is.

Obs: Zoom is not working. The html page doesn't have it enabled. And I think its not a good way, since zoom doesn't change the perceived webview size.

Comment: Have you looked into the guide on Zooming a View on the Android Dev site? It may help.. http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html#setup

Comment: yep. Doesn't seem to do. "Expanding" the view doesn't make the page's html behave differently.

Comment: Hmm.. You could try switching the user agent to make the site appear as if it were on a desktop browser, that may make it better on a tablet

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update: If you have a newer API (> 18) you may want to take a look at the note at the end of this question.

---

After struggling for quite a bit I found the solution!

The solution was not on zoomming. The zoom wasn't enabled for the html page and it didn't affect the size perceived by the html.

I got it by lowering the **width** of the webview:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams webviewLayoutParameters = mWebView.getLayoutParams();

webviewLayoutParameters.width = (int) (760);
webviewLayoutParameters.height =(int) (webviewHeight);
mWebView.setLayoutParams(webviewLayoutParameters);
```

Then, as the page had a style that changed for screen sizes lower than 768px, it started to look different. Much better.

But then **I wanted to enlarge that small webview so it could fit on the whole screen**. For that I used `scaleX` and `scaleY`.

This is my complete commented solution:

```
// First, get the current screen size
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int displayWidth = size.x;
int displayHeight = size.y;

//Then, set the amount you want to make your screen smaller. This means that it will comunicate to the HTML that its 20% smaller than it really is
float amplification_ratio = (float) 0.20;

// Shrink webview size
ViewGroup.LayoutParams webviewLayoutParameters = mWebView.getLayoutParams();
webviewLayoutParameters.width = (int) (displayWidth*(1-amplification_ratio));
webviewLayoutParameters.height =(int) (displayHeight*(1-amplification_ratio));
mWebView.setLayoutParams(webviewLayoutParameters);

// Now scale it the inverse ammount so it will take the full screen.
mWebView.setScaleX(1/(1 - amplification_ratio));
mWebView.setScaleY(1/(1 - amplification_ratio));
```

It worked pretty well. I managed to scale it in a way that changes the screen size. The shrinking and scaling will make the image quality a little lower, but its not a big deal.

**Obs**: The HTML page was made in bootstrap and only had classes for bootstrap's `-xs` devices. So I had to simulate the screen was smaller than 768px.

---

**Obs2 (update): Naming this procedure**

I implemented this on my app, tested it (model and integration), and its now live in production. To create the functions and variables, I had to name this procedure. What this does is like increasing the size of a webview pixel. In this way, the webview will still take thw whole screen, but it will have a width, in pixels, that is smaller.

With that in mind, any name like `pixelEnlargementFactor`, `pixelMagnificationRatio` or `pixelSizeMultiplicator` will be a good name.

---

**UPDATE:**

WARNING: Use the method above only in specific cases!

I had an old API version (15) and Had a `RelativeLayout` with many options. Back then, the `setInitialScale(120)` didn't work as I wanted.

Now I've changed my API to 19 and my layout to a simpler `FrameLayout` with fewer options. Now the `setInitialScale(120)` command along with `mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false)` did all what I achieved before with much less code.